# Is there a better way to write this simple line of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery and I have written a very simple script that works great. Now I would like to find out if there is a better way to write this line.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $('div.beforeRecover').animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, 300).delay(800);
    $('div.betweenRecover').animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, 200).delay(1200);
    $('div.betweenRecover').animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, 800);
    $('div.afterRecover').delay(1800).animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, 1400);
    return false;
});
```

To briefly explain:

1. Form gets submitted
2. Form fades
3. Loading gif appears
4. Loading gif fades
5. Confirmation message appears.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you're wanting to display a "Loading" graphic while the form is being submitted, I'd suggest fading the form and showing the gif, then using ajax to submit the form and use the completion callbacks of the ajax call to hide the gif and show the message. The form submission might be faster or slower depending on various conditions

Comment: @MrOBrian: Yes, that's a good suggestion that goes beyond simple refactoring.

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I'll direct any further review questions to this URL. ALso, thanks MrOBrian, I was thinking about using AJAX on this form. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fadeToggle = { opacity: 'toggle' };

$("form").submit(function() {

    $('div.beforeRecover').animate(fadeToggle, 300).delay(800);

    $('div.betweenRecover')
        .animate(fadeToggle, 200).delay(1200)
        .animate(fadeToggle, 800).delay(1800);

    $('div.afterRecover').animate(fadeToggle, 1400);

    return false;
});
```

Infact, there is a whole separate method called [**`.fadeToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Comment: Thanks, I had no knowledge of fadeToggle, much appreciated.